# If I have taken IPv4 CIDR block as 10.10.0.0/16 then how many IP addresses should be available

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, amazon-vpc, ipv4, cidr

**I have created a VPC on aws with IPv4 CIDR block as 10.10.0.0/16**

As per my understanding , The IP address range what's available should be from 10.10.0.0 to 10.10.255.255 .In other words , it should have 2^16 = 65536 IP addresses available . Is it correct ?

But when I am filling things in AWS , it's showing as this 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's not a correct assumption. x.x.x.0 and x.x.x.255 are reserved addresses everywhere, not only AWS. As for others:

```
    10.0.0.0: Network address.

    10.0.0.1: Reserved by AWS for the VPC router.

    10.0.0.2: Reserved by AWS. The IP address of the DNS server is the base of the VPC network range plus two. For VPCs with multiple CIDR blocks, the IP address of the DNS server is located in the primary CIDR. We also reserve the base of each subnet range plus two for all CIDR blocks in the VPC. For more information, see Amazon DNS server.

    10.0.0.3: Reserved by AWS for future use.

    10.0.0.255: Network broadcast address. We do not support broadcast in a VPC, therefore we reserve this address.
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html